# C# background worker not triggering dowork event on any pc besides my own

Tags: c#, events, backgroundworker, eventtrigger

I'm having a really weird issue with a background worker in one of my applications. I recently overhauled it slightly with some GUI fixes but now when someone on another PC runs the .exe or installs my OneClick deployment the background worker doesn't enter the dowork event. The logic has not changed between the 2 releases. I've done a compare and besides adding more error logging nothing has changed.

I've gone as far as to include message boxes and breakpoints in the dowork event but it never enters it anywhere besides on my own PC. Even when i remote debug it doesnt enter the DoWork event

Any suggestions?

Button click even calls the runworkerasync event

```
private void ScanButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Scan = new BackgroundWorker();
        Scan.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        Scan.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Scan_DoWork);
        Scan.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(Scan_ProgressChanged);
        Scan.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Scan_RunWorkerCompleted);
        Scan.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Below is the code that runs the DoWork event. Ive removed the other functions it does for simplicity. All it does is run a function that returns a string and places it inside of the list called scanresults.

```
private BackgroundWorker Scan;

    public void Scan_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Inside the DoWork");

        BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        float percentageDone = 0.0F;

        ScanResults = new List<string>();

        try
        {

            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Doing first scan check");

            ScanResults.Add(Functions.LocalComputerName());
            percentageDone = ((1 / 1f) * 100f);
            bw.ReportProgress((int)percentageDone);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Encountered", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
        }
    }


public void Scan_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ScanResults.Count == 0)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Empty");
                return;
            }
            MachineNameBox.Text = ScanResults[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Encountered", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
        }
    }
```

It completely ignores the dowork event and enters the runworkercomplete event and passes a error for the index obviously because the list hasnt been filled as the function  do that has been skipped. Again this works perfectly on my PC but not on others no matter how i release it to them.

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Inside the DoWork"); probably won't work from inside a BackgroundWorker. Set e.Result to the exception in DoWork and check if e.Result contains an exception in the RunWorkerCompleted event.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My *guess* is that your `DoWork` is throwing an exception and so your `RunWorkerCompleted` is called.

Note that exceptions thrown in a BGW's `DoWork` method will not be caught in a try...catch in `RunWorkerCompleted`; instead, the pattern is to check if the `Error` property in `RunWorkerCompleted`'s `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` parameter is not null.  If this is not null, you have an exception.

You might rework your `RunWorkerCompleted` code like this:

```
public void Scan_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Error != null) {
        // You have an exception, which you can examine through the e.Error property.
    } else {
        // No exception in DoWork.
        try {
            if (ScanResults.Count == 0) {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Empty");
                return;
            }
            MachineNameBox.Text = ScanResults[0];
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Encountered", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
        }
    }
}
```

See [BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) for more info and a better example than mine.

Comment: Thanks that helped me find the issue. One of my Dll's was corrupted some how, rebuilt it and now its working properly again. Much appreciated!

Comment: I had this issue as well today, logging the exception message turned out to be just what I needed to fix the problem, and oddly enough, it was because we didn't have the right version of a DLL in place on our client's computers.

Comment: This worked for me.  My background worker is embedded in a MS Excel Add In.  I could not see the e.Error result logs until I had the client repair their Excel.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was that my main project was signed and the new DLL I brought in was not.  It's weird because I never got a warning or error and the project compiled ok.  Just that the background_dowork() would never even get hit in debug.  Once I added in the signing cert on the DLL it started that backgroundworker just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Jay Riggs' answer is the right one, but I just wanted to add that exceptions caused by certain issues in DoWork *won't even be caught by a `try...catch` in `DoWork`*, which was amazing to me.

I had a situation where my `DoWork` routine used a third party library which in turn used another library, which was missing. When my application called `DoWork`, *even though the library wasn't used right away* and *even though the entire method was wrapped in a `try...catch`*, it failed *outside the method* and called `RunWorkerCompleted` as if all was well. So the background job did nothing but also didn't throw an exception, it just quietly put the exception in the `Error` property, which I was ignoring, because I never knew about it. This took some very careful debugging to uncover.

My takeaway is that you always need to check for an error in `RunWorkerCompleted` and that this is very counter-intuitive behavior. If Jay Riggs' answer wasn't here, I can't imagine how long it would have taken to figure it out.